# Android quotes not getting parsed

Tags: android, parser-generator, xml-parsing

I am using the following code to parse the RSS feeds. It does not work if the quotes appear. Please help.

```
public static ArrayList<RssItem> getRssItems(String feedUrl) {

        ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();

        try {
            //open an URL connection make GET to the server and 
            //take xml RSS data
            URL url = new URL(feedUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                //DocumentBuilderFactory, DocumentBuilder are used for 
                //xml parsing
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                //using db (Document Builder) parse xml data and assign
                //it to Element
                Document document = db.parse(is);
                Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

                //take rss nodes to NodeList
                NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("item");

                if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                        //take each entry (corresponds to <item></item> tags in 
                        //xml data

                        Element entry = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

                        Element _titleE = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "title").item(0);
                        Element _descriptionE = (Element) entry
                                .getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);
                        Element _pubDateE = (Element) entry
                                .getElementsByTagName("pubDate").item(0);
                        Element _linkE = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                                "link").item(0);

                        String _title = _titleE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        String _description = _descriptionE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        Date _pubDate = new Date(_pubDateE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        String _link = _linkE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                        //create RssItemObject and add it to the ArrayList
                        RssItem rssItem = new RssItem(_title, _description,
                                _pubDate, _link);

                        rssItems.add(rssItem);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rssItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming there is only one text node in the elements (`getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`). That is a mistaken assumption. You will need to iterate over all the child nodes of the elements and combine your text nodes.

Comment: ware. Can you please give an example code. please. I am new to android.